# Remotely configure a computer to auto restart after power loss

Tags: boot, power-supply, reboot

I am currently located on the West Coast, while my target PC is situated on the East Coast at a retail store. To remotely access it, I'm using the Kaseya Agent.

However, I want to change the PC settings so that it automatically restarts after a power loss when the AC power is connected. The problem is that I cannot access the BIOS, and I don't have anyone who is computer-savvy enough to help me with this process.

Is there any way to do this without accessing the BIOS?

Comment: [There are remote KVM devices that could support this but they would already need to be supported to use them.](https://pikvm.org/). But, no the option you have to enable, is in the firmware settings

Comment: Then just get a person there to start the computer. Everyone can do that.

Comment: Or, hire a local contractor  (at the site in question) to set up remote start for you. That is another workable possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Use a software that can modify the Bios without having to restart and get physically to the BIOS options.
We have a Lenovo computer and we did that by installing their software
https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/software/think-bios-config-tool/

Comment: Even if you can save the BIOS changes, you have to restart to make the changes effective.

Comment: Thank you. It's an HP, so I'm sure that I'll be able to find something similar.